# Want to Speed up If Statement

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, vba

I'm looking at trying to speed up my nested If statement below if possible since it goes through each row in my column. This has an impact on the run time of my macro:

```
Set Col = Range("O2:O" & lastrowOU3)
For Each Cell In Col
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = 0 Then Cell.Value = "NEW ITEM"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "VALIDATED" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 1"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED 1" Then Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 2"
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) >= Date Then Cell.Value = "VALIDATED"
Next
```

Is there a way of avoiding going through each scenario once one of the above is met so macro goes straight to next row? Or perhaps theres an even quicker way?

Thanks,

Conor

Comment: 1.) IF/ELSEIF/ENDIF 2.) place the values in variables so it goes to the sheet only twice per loop.

Comment: If you want it even faster, use Excel formula instead of VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an "ElseIf" will mean that tests will only be done if the previous steps are not True.

```
Set Col = Range("O2:O" & lastrowOU3)
For Each Cell In Col
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = 0 Then
    Cell.Value = "NEW ITEM"
ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then
    Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then
    Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "VALIDATED" Then
    Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED" Then
    Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 1"
ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED 1" Then
    Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 2"
ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -2) >= Date Then
    Cell.Value = "VALIDATED"
End If
Next
```

Nesting the statements will also speed things up a bit more:

```
Set Col = Range("O2:O" & lastrowOU3)
For Each Cell In Col
If Cell.Offset(0, -2) = 0 Then
    IF And Cell.Offset(0, -1) = 0 Then
        Cell.Value = "NEW ITEM"
    ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then
        Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
    End If
ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -2) < Date Then
    If Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NEW ITEM" Then
        Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
    ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "VALIDATED" Then
        Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
    ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED" Then
        Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 1"
    ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -1) = "NOT VALIDATED 1" Then
        Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 2"
    End If
ElseIf Cell.Offset(0, -2) >= Date Then
    Cell.Value = "VALIDATED"
End If
Next
```

And using SELECT CASE statements will probably speed it up even more, as each "Cell.Offset(0, x)" will only need to be evaluated once (I think):

```
Set Col = Range("O2:O" & lastrowOU3)
For Each Cell In Col
Select Case Cell.Offset(0, -2)
    Case 0
        Select Case Cell.Offset(0, -1)
            Case 0
                Cell.Value = "NEW ITEM"
            Case "NEW ITEM"
                Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
            Case Else
        End Select
    Case < Date
        Select Case Cell.Offset(0, -1)
            Case "NEW ITEM"
                Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
            Case "VALIDATED"
                Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED"
            Case "NOT VALIDATED"
                Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 1"
            Case "NOT VALIDATED 1"
                Cell.Value = "NOT VALIDATED 2"
            Case Else
        End Select
    Case Else
        Cell.Value = "VALIDATED"
End Select
Next
```

Comment: Cheers mate. Was nearly there. Appreciate your help on a Sunday!

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum:

```
Sub dural()
    Set Col = Range("O2:O" & lastrowOU3)
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, s As String

    For Each cell In Col
        v1 = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
        v2 = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If v1 = 0 And v2 = 0 Then s = "NEW ITEM"
        If v1 = 0 And v2 = "NEW ITEM" Then s = "NOT VALIDATED"
        If v1 < Date And v2 = "NEW ITEM" Then s = "NOT VALIDATED"
        If v1 < Date And v2 = "VALIDATED" Then s = "NOT VALIDATED"
        If v1 < Date And v2 = "NOT VALIDATED" Then s = "NOT VALIDATED 1"
        If v1 < Date And v2 = "NOT VALIDATED 1" Then s = "NOT VALIDATED 2"
        If v1 >= Date Then s = "VALIDATED"
        cell.Value = s
    Next
End Sub
```